# Serial DTR line on reboot

Tags: serial-port

I'm working on a controller board that connects to the PC via the serial port.  We'd like to be able to reboot this board from the PC.  I have another system at work that seems to accomplish this using the DTR line, e.g. pulses the line for a certain period to trigger a reboot.  I would like to find information on what the standard state of the line is (e.g. is it usually logic high or low) and what happens to the line when the PC reboots (e.g. does it de-assert for a period).

Thanks to anyone who can help,
Fred

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not write a simple app that runs at startup and asserts DTR for some specified amount of time?

Comment: I will have a program that controls the DTR, I would like to know what the expected behavior is of the line on a PC reboot however.

Comment: It probably depends on the type of serial port you have.  Mine is a USB and it does not appear to assert DTR on restart, but my break out box does not have the ability to latch a signal, so it might for a very brief amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some updated information about my USB SerialPorts(usbsp).

I rebooted a couple of times and my usbsp **does** go through some sequence of raising and lowering signals when my PC reboots.  It also does this when any(a couple I tried) new USB device is plugged in.

So beware if you are using usbsp's signals at boot time to control a device.

Comment: Absolutely.  Each controller does its own thing, and you cannot rely on it to be standard.

Comment: After my initial comment I paid closer attention.  I just bought a new USB serial port adapter.  If it does something different I'll post back.  As you said, don't rely on it to be standard.